# How can I get the Mechanist's suit back?

Tags: fallout-3

Short story, I sold the Mechanist's armor to a caravan and then entered the Ant-agonizer's lair. Can I get it back?

Long story, I was scavenging when I came to the town where those to guys whose names I find too long to type again, have their fight. I went for the Ant-agonizer first then realized her lair was ridiculously close to the town, so I did the Mechanist's hideout first, used a successful dialogue option and he dumped his suit on me. Overencumbered, I dropped the heaviest thing in my inventory(His suit), used the grab button so it was just floating in front of me, and high-tailed it to the town's merchant. They don't have one. So I waited for a caravan, sold my non-essentials(his suit and helmet included), and began the Ant-agonizer's Lair.

She says she won't talk to me until I have the suit.

Can I get it back?

Comment: you might be able to use the [console](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Gamebryo_console_commands)

Comment: That's awesome. But I'm playing it on PS3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The traders use a fixed route, so if you go to one of the locations below, wait for the first caravan to show up and see if they have the Mechanist's suit in their inventory. If not, wait 2 hours in game time or use the 'select' button to wait. Repeat this until you have checked the four caravans mentioned below.

If this doesn't work, I would assume that the items are lost forever in the wasteland I'm afraid. There is no information on whether the trade caravans retain sold items, but given that the normal merchants seem to, I'd say there is a good chance that the trade caravans also do.

```
The traders use a fixed route.  They travel from location to location, 
and they only stop at the places listed below.  They always visit them 
in the order listed, and they follow after each other: Doc Hoff, then 
Crazy Wolfgang, Crow, Lucky Harith.  If you meet Doc Hoff in
Megaton you'll know you can meet Crazy Wolfgang if you wait 2 hours 
(with the wait-function).

Ask Uncle Roe about the Map that pinpoints how the Caravan Traders trek.

Caravan Trader Route:

o Canterbury Commons
o Temple of the Union
o Agatha's House
o Paradise Falls
o Arefu
o Evergreen Mills
o Megaton
o Rivet City
```

Source: http://www.supercheats.com/guides/fallout-3/trade-caravans

Comment: It was Wolfgang, and I found him again, but I must have waited too long because his items reset. But thank you, I wish I had known this before.

Comment: I'm not sure if the caravans use the same rules of retaining your sold items as the normal merchants seem to, I guess worst case, you'll need to revert to a save game before you sold the items if you want to complete the quest now.